# How to trigger workflow on Account after lead conversion?

Tags: workflow, lead-conversion

as far I can remember there is leadid that is accessible from API, but in workflow formula it is not.

Is there a way to run workflow on newly created (converted) account?

My immediate idea is to create hidden, default on, checkbox on lead, which would be mapped on to accounts as well. Pretty simple, but isn't there other way?

p.s. Enforce Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert is enabled.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.  The hidden checkbox on the lead and account is the most straightforward way. Then your workflow criteria can watch for that box to be checked.